# Create categorized rendered from styles in QGIS 3.4.3

Tags: qgis, style

How does this tool work? I've been trying to use it but it needs xml file and I dont know how to create one and running the tool without inputting a style database returns a single colorised map

Is the option of saving a style in postgresql no longer available in QGIS 3.4.3?

Tool under Cartography toolset

Image showing: no option to save style as style db visible
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. In the categorized render, basically you select your column of interest, after you press the classify button and then you press ok.
   (you can define more classes, change colors, add some effects,... so all what you can do with a single symbol)

[image]

2. The option saving in a database is there in QGis 3.x as you can see below

[image]

Comment: I have added the screenshot in the original question. I'm getting the save as style db in my QGIS (Version 3.4.3)